# Remove SearchView search voice button line

Tags: android, searchview

Thanks to other SO related posts regarding `SearchView` customisation I was able to customise my `SearchView` to this point:

[image]

Now I'm trying to add voice search and I was able to change the voice button background resource:

```
int searchVoiceIconId = searchPlate.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_voice_btn", null, null);
ImageView searchVoiceIcon = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(searchVoiceIconId);
searchVoiceIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_mic);
searchVoiceIcon.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

However, I can't seem to get rid of the line under the voice search button.

[image]

any suggestions????

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is a late reply but it might be helpful for future.

Add the following line:

```
<style name="AppTheme.SearchView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <!-- Gets rid of the "underline" in the mic button-->
    <item name="submitBackground">@null</item>
```

To your values/styles.xml file and it will remove the line.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
((LinearLayout)search.findViewById(R.id.search_voice_btn).getParent()).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Comment: I'm getting an exception: 04-27 10:13:15.740: E/AndroidRuntime(16189): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewParent android.view.View.getParent()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

```
int submitAreaId = searchView.getContext().getResources()
                .getIdentifier("android:id/submit_area", null, null);
View submitAreaView = searchView.findViewById(submitAreaId);
if (submitAreaView != null) {
    submitAreaView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
}
```

This should remove any underline of the non text input area.